# How do I convert a unicode string to turkish in java?

Tags: java, android, unicode

Hi, I want to convert the unicode value "\u20BA" to the Turkish equivalent string. Can anybody help me please?

I used the following code:

```
try {
  String string = "\u20BA";
  System.out.println(string + " " + string.toLowerCase());
  // Locale.setDefault(new Locale("tr"));
  // Locale tr = new Locale("TR","tr");
  byte[] converttoBytes = string.toLowerCase().getBytes("UTF-8");
  string = new String(converttoBytes, "Cp1254");
  System.out.println(string + " " + string.toLowerCase());
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by converting a character (apparently U+20BA TURKISH LIRA SIGN, introduced in Unicode 6.2) “to turkish” or “to the Turkish equivalent string”? To a word in the Turkish language? The code shows no such attempt. Do you mean converting to the CP 1254 character encoding? To begin with, it does not contain U+20BA.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a `String` in Java as a sequence of characters independent of any character encoding. It therefore does not make sense to speak about changing the encoding of a `String`.

Character encodings only come to play if you convert between characters and bytes. This usually happens when you read or write characters from/to a `Stream` of bytes (for example  a file). If you don't specify the encoding explicitly the platform encoding gets used.

In case of difficulties make sure your platform encoding is set correctly or specify the correct encoding explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you're specifying the code point for an individual character, but you're using that code point as the input to a `String` object, so Java's interpreting it as 6 separate characters. Try this for your specific question:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('\u20BA');
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Note that the Unicode value is in single quotes - a single character value. As you may have guessed, you can continue appending other Unicode values in this way to create a string...however, as has been mentioned, this might not be the best answer to whatever underlying problem you're working on.

Comment: What IDE are you using, or are you doing something else in your code? I tested that snippet before I posted it; it prints a Turkish Lira sign.

Answer (score 0):

The [lira sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira_sign) (u+20BA) was created in 2012 and both [CP1254](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305147.aspx) and [ISO-8859-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9) character set doesn't have the lira sign included.

This can be proven on Linux with the following set of commands (u+20BA is actually encoded as the 3 following bytes in utf8: E2 82 BA):

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x82\xBA"
₺
$ echo -e "\xE2\x82\xBA" | iconv --from utf8 --to cp1254
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
$ echo -e "\xE2\x82\xBA" | iconv --from utf8 --to iso88599
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
$ echo -e "\xE2\x82\xBA" | iconv --from utf8 --to cp1254//TRANSLIT
?
$ echo -e "\xE2\x82\xBA" | iconv --from utf8 --to iso88599//TRANSLIT
?
```